# Смена части кода сайта

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток. Сначала, что имею:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        NewImg = new Array("image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg");
        var ImgNum = 0;
        var ImgLength = NewImg.length - 1;
        var delay = 5000;
        var lock = false;
        var run;

        function chgImg(direction) {
            if (document.images) {
                ImgNum = ImgNum + direction;
                if (ImgNum > ImgLength) {
                    ImgNum = 0;
                }
                if (ImgNum < 0) {
                    ImgNum = ImgLength;
                }
                document.slideshow.src = NewImg[ImgNum];
            }
        }

        function auto() {
            if (lock == true) {
                lock = false;
                window.clearInterval(run);
            } else if (lock == false) {
                lock = true;
                run = setInterval("chgImg(1)", delay);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <img src="image1.jpg" name="slideshow">
                <br>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:chgImg(-1)">    Back</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:auto()">        Play / Stop</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:chgImg(1)">     Next</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

В данном коде имеется несколько картинок, которые поочередно меняются. Собственно работает идеально, но охота большего.

1. Подскажите, как сделать, что бы менялась не картинка, а прописанный код? Допустим, пару слов и картинка. Или целая таблица?
2. Можно ли каким то образом сделать, в место простой смены возможность появления и исчезания (или перелистывания), так сказать, для кода, который указал в п1? (Естественно с возможностью вкл. или выкл. этот эффект.)

P.S. Я, конечно, могу погуглить, на тему слайдшоу, но меня интересует, так сказать, "кашерный" вариант, в хорошем смысле слова. 8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы содержимое тега надо делать так:

```
<div id="txt">
Старое содержимое 
<div>
<script>
var txt1=document.getElementById("txt1");
txt1.innerHTML="Новое содержимое";
</script>
```

А чтоб сделать плавное затухание/появление надо изменять `opacity`